# Authentication using google and facebook very slow

Tags: django, facebook, google-oauth, django-socialauth

I use django social auth for authentication in my website.I use the providers google-oauth2, facebook and github.The google and facebook login is boringly slow, whereas github login works perfect.

URL : dyuthi.in

The google and facebook login does not fail,but however, completes after atleast 30 seconds.The page waits for the redirect from authentication server to my site.

Answer (score 1):

I have an integration right now with both Google OAuth 2 login and Facebook basic login, and neither of them is terribly fast, but they usually take less than 5 seconds, including all the back-and-forth.   Can you offer more details?

Comment: What kind of details should i provide?

Answer (score 1):

Mine all of sudden is now slow. It's used to take under 3 sec... it's now taking 20+ sec at the most. And for Facebook... it's not even validating anymore. Cannot getUser(). It always returns 0.

Comment: My issue was i used the weong python version of the packages.I was on a webfaction hosting that provided 4 python versions.I installed dsa for python2.4 and copied it to the folder of python 2.7.Reinstalling solved the issue

Comment: i'm not sure what's going on... but all of a sudden my facebook and google oauth is working just fine again. They are authenticating under 3 seconds. It must be my dedicated server connection issues in the past few days.